# Is there a formula for d_2 of the de Rham spectral sequence of a fiber bundle with a connection?

Tags: connections, spectral-sequences, de-rham-cohomology

The de Rham spectral sequence of a fiber bundle with a connection was studied by Hattori in a paper of essentially that as title. He works out E_0,d_0 and E_1, d_1 and E_2 but not d_2. Has it been done? where?

Comment: this one might do better at mathoverflow

Comment: Would love to help out the real @jimstasheff but unfortunately not familiar with this.  Agree with trying mathoverflow.